# Line highlighting canceling out syntax highlighting

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, overlays, highlighting

I use `hl-line-mode` and I really like the built-in `misterioso` theme. However, the way that lines are highlighted with this theme cancels out syntax highlighting or any other properties of the highlighted lines, as can be seen in this screenshot. 
[image]

How can I keep the highlighting the same color, but avoid covering up the face properties of the highlighted text? I would be willing to compromise and change the color if necessary, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I have tried changing the color, but still get the same effect. I have also tried [this solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10463/8430), but only succeeded in getting rid of highlighting altogether.

[This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10445/8430) seems to be the same or similar to mine, but I am honestly not sure if it is the same. I tried the solution suggested there but couldn't get it to work. Rather than having a discussion in the comments of that question, I thought I would ask a new one, but my feelings will not be hurt if this gets marked as duplicate.

Comment: I don't think the question you link to is a duplicate because it deals with the overriding of the background, while you're dealing with the overriding of the foreground.

Comment: @PythonNut: Seems like the same question to me, whether it is foreground or background. I'd say you should consider adding your answer to that question (swapping foreground & background) and this one should be closed as a duplicate. But this one might be expressed more clearly - not sure what's more kosher in such a case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hl-line-mode hide background, how to avoid this?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10445/hl-line-mode-hide-background-how-to-avoid-this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the `hl-line` face is defining a `:foreground` property, which is overriding the other foreground colors in your theme.

`misterioso` defines `hl-line` in terms of `highlight` using inheritance, and because of an awkward issue (which I asked about [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19947/unset-inherited-face-attribute)), it's not possible AFAIK to directly inherit from a face, and override one of the properties to be unset.

So instead, you'll need something like this:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'hl-line nil
                    :inherit nil
                    :background (face-background 'highlight))
```

This may not be as clean as a hypothetical solution that could preserve the inheritance, but it works.

---

As noted by Stefan, another solution would be to remove the foreground from the `highlight` face, which would fix this issue for other types of highlights as well.

```el
(set-face-foreground 'highlight nil)
```

Comment: A better solution is probably to change the `highlight` face to not specify any foreground.

Comment: Both of these solutions don't seem to be working when running emacs in X (GUI) mode, but work nice in `-nw`.