# Highlight current line without changing colours

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlighting, hl-line-mode

I use (global-hl-line-mode 1) in order to highlight the current line.
This changes the text colours of the highlighted line. Is it possible to highlight while keeping the current syntax highlighting colours (so changing only the background)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hl-line-mode hide background, how to avoid this?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10445/hl-line-mode-hide-background-how-to-avoid-this)

Comment: No. Overlay highlighting (which is used by `hl-line-mode`) always overrides text-property highlighting (e.g. font-lock). See the question this is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 8):

Just for reference, try

```
(set-face-attribute 'hl-line nil :inherit nil :background "gray6")
```

Comment: Please consider elaborating, explaining how this answers the question.

Comment: It does not work for me

Answer (score 5):

This is the case by default for me: `hl-line-mode` by default uses a face which only specifies a background color.  That face is `hl-line` which by default just inherits from `highlight`.  So maybe the problem is simply your that `highlight` face specifies both a background and a foreground color.  I recommend you `M-x customize-face` and either change your `highlight` face or your `hl-line` face so as to keep its foreground color unspecified.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me, with this in my .emacs. See how the syntax colours are nicely preserved? (thx Yadoo86)

```
;; highlight line with the cursor, preserving the colours.
(set-face-attribute 'hl-line nil :inherit nil :background "gray80")
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
```

[image]